# Meaning of valid sequent in logics

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

If $$\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3.......\alpha_{k-2}, \alpha_{k-1}, \alpha_k\vdash\alpha$$

Here $\alpha_i$ are premises and $\alpha$ is conclusion .If I prove that sequent is valid using given rules in books does that mean that I proved If all $\alpha_i$ are true then $\alpha$ is true.

Comment: Yes. If the logic you work with is *sound*, then any syntactical proof must be valid with respect to any *model*.

Comment: then why don't we write  'and operation' on all premises implies conclusion.

Comment: Are you meaning : $\alpha_1 \land \ldots \land \alpha_k \vdash \alpha$ ? If so, for two basic reasons : (1) the language can have only some primitive connectives (like : $\to, \lnot$) without $\land$ being present, and the relation of *derivability* ($\vdash$) still holds. (2) We can state the relation as $\Sigma \vdash \alpha$, where $\Sigma$ is a *set* of premises, possibly infinite; in this case, we want that the relation of derivability is defined also if the syntax of the language (as usual) does not allow to write "infinitely long" formulae (as an infinite conjunction).